# How to install Java 8 in Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit?

Tags: java

I am new to Ubuntu, I want work on Hadoop with Java. And don't want to get Java from a third party. How to install Java? I try to install with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install open jdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package open
E: Unable to locate package jdk-7-jdk
```

Is this correct command?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is past end-of-life. Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install default-jre`
`sudo apt-get install default-jdk`
or:
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` 
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`